# Vagrant unable to pulling from a private docker registry (authentication) and being prompted for password on rsync

Tags: vagrant

Working on a Vagrant file recently, trying to build my project which consist of multiple dockers (app, redis)

These are the version am using

```
Vagrant 1.8.1
hashicorp/boot2docker (virtualbox, 1.7.8)
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

Here is also my vagrant file

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|


    config.vm.define 'app' do |app|
        app.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            app.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
            app.vm.provision "file", source: "~/.docker/config.json", destination: "~/.docker/config.json"
            app.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo cp -R /home/vagrant/.docker /root/.docker"
            app.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo Hello"
            d.build_dir = "."
            d.remains_running = false
        end
    end

end
```

Am actually facing two separate problems

1) It seems like when syncing the folder am prompted for a password, for some reason I found online someone has wrote to use `tcuser` as a password and it worked. But, I would like to not have that, any suggestion?

2) The docker image am trying to build is actually references another image which is on a private docker registery on `AWS ECR` so am trying to upload `.docker/config.json` to allow authentication but its not working for me.

Below is the output am seeing

```
Bringing machine 'app' up with 'docker' provider...
==> app: Docker host is required. One will be created if necessary...
    app: Vagrant will now create or start a local VM to act as the Docker
    app: host. You'll see the output of the `vagrant up` for this VM below.
    app:  
    default: Box 'hashicorp/boot2docker' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
    default: Loading metadata for box 'hashicorp/boot2docker'
    default: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/boot2docker
    default: Adding box 'hashicorp/boot2docker' (v1.7.8) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/boxes/boot2docker/versions/1.7.8/providers/virtualbox.box
    default: Successfully added box 'hashicorp/boot2docker' (v1.7.8) for 'virtualbox'!
    default: Importing base box 'hashicorp/boot2docker'...
    default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
    default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/boot2docker' is up to date...
    default: Setting the name of the VM: docker-host_default_1455753187095_3647
    default: Fixed port collision for 2375 => 2375. Now on port 2204.
    default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2205.
    default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
    default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 2375 (guest) => 2204 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2205 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
    default: Booting VM...
    default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2205
    default: SSH username: docker
    default: SSH auth method: password
    default: Machine booted and ready!
==> app: Syncing folders to the host VM...
    default: Installing rsync to the VM...
    default: The machine you're rsyncing folders to is configured to use
    default: password-based authentication. Vagrant can't script rsync to automatically
    default: enter this password, so you'll likely be prompted for a password
    default: shortly.
    default: 
    default: If you don't want to have to do this, please enable automatic
    default: key insertion using `config.ssh.insert_key`.
    default: Rsyncing folder: /Users/xx/Projects/proj/ => /var/lib/docker/docker_build_930d43a6c182bc70b5cb41a97523c5c6
docker@127.0.0.1's password: 
==> app: Building the container from a Dockerfile...
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 557.1 kB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 1.114 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 1.671 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.228 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.785 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.342 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.899 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 4.456 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 5.014 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 5.571 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 6.128 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 6.685 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 7.242 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 7.799 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 8.356 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 8.913 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon  9.47 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 10.03 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 10.58 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 11.14 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon  11.7 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 12.26 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 12.81 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 13.37 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 13.93 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 14.48 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 15.04 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon  15.6 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 16.15 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 16.71 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 17.27 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 17.83 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 18.38 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 18.94 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon  19.5 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 20.05 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 20.61 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 21.17 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 21.73 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 22.28 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 22.84 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon  23.4 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 23.95 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 24.51 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 25.07 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 25.62 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 26.18 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 26.74 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon  27.3 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 27.85 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 28.18 MB
    app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 
    app: Step 0 : FROM id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/image:latest
    app: Pulling repository id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/image
    app: Authentication is required.
A Docker command executed by Vagrant didn't complete successfully!
The command run along with the output from the command is shown
below.

Command: "docker" "build" "/var/lib/docker/docker_build_930d43a6c182bc70b5cb41a97523c5c6"

Stderr: Authentication is required.

Sending build context to Docker daemon 28.18 MB557.1 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/image:latest
Pulling repository id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/image
```

Answer (score 0):

Im fairly new to vagrant myself. However i was able to pull from private docker registry by using the shell provisioner in vagrant before the docker provisioner.

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

    # Shared folders
    config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", type: "smb"

    config.vm.provision "docker"

    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "docker login --username='user' --password='pass' my-private-registry"

    config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
        d.pull_images "my-private-registry-image"
    end
end
```

For the problem with rsync asking for a password I think you can set a password on when using sync_folders, for example

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", type: "rsync", username: "user", password: "pass"
```

However I would not recommend this as your password is there for all to see. Hope this helps